# How to debug in Jcreator?

Tags: jcreator

I am using JCreator version 5.0.0.10. And I do not know how to debug a program. Could you please specify step by step with pictures included?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

JCreator LE does not have a debugger.

If you have JCreator Pro, it's just a matter of setting a breakpoint, clicking "Run" in the menu and then either "Debug File" or "Debug Project".

Comment: Hi, thank. Now i know my problem. It is because i am using JCreator LE :(

Comment: Check out Eclipse at http://www.eclipse.org/ It's a much nicer IDE, and it's also free. Also, please select this as the answer if it was helpful to you.