# How to run Java project in JCreator Line by line?

Tags: java, breakpoints, jcreator

I need to run my java project in JCreator line by line. As in VS 2010 we put a break point and get the value at that point, I want to do similar task in JCreator.

Is there any way to do this in JCreator?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466400/how-to-debug-in-jcreator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to run into serious challenges if you are using the free version of JCreator, as it's missing most of the tools that are worth having once you get into development.

Perhaps you'd be best served looking at a free, full IDE like [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org) or [NetBeans](http://www.netbeans.org). As you keep comparing a light-weight tool like JCreator with Visual Studio, I can only guess that you want the full benefit of a large IDE.