# Function Trouble in Java Programming 2

Tags: java, function

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Palindrome
{
    public static String PalindromeChecker(String original,String reverse)
    {
        String func1="";
        Scanner peace=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("\n\nEnter a string to check if it is a palindrome");
        original=peace.nextLine();
        int length=original.length();
        for(int i=length-1;i>=0;i--)
            reverse=reverse+original.charAt(i);
            if (original.equals(reverse))
                System.out.println("\n\nEntered string is a palindrome.");
            else
                System.out.println("\n\nEntered string is not a palindrome.");
        return func1;   
    }
    public static void CharacterNumberCounter(String original) 
    {
        int letters=0,digits=0,blanks=0,length=0;
        char ch;
        for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
        {
            ch=original.charAt(i);
            if(ch=='a'||ch=='A'||ch=='b'||ch=='B'||ch=='c'|| 
            ch=='C'||ch=='d'||ch=='D'||ch=='e'||ch=='E'||
            ch=='f'||ch=='F'||ch=='g'||ch=='G'||ch=='h'|| 
            ch=='H'||ch=='i'||ch=='I'||ch=='j'||ch=='J'||
            ch=='k'||ch=='K'||ch=='l'||ch=='L'||ch=='m'|| 
            ch=='M'||ch=='n'||ch=='N'||ch=='o'||ch=='O'||
            ch=='p'||ch=='P'||ch=='q'||ch=='Q'||ch=='r'|| 
            ch=='R'||ch=='s'||ch=='S'||ch=='t'||ch=='T'||
            ch=='u'||ch=='U'||ch=='v'||ch=='V'||ch=='w'|| 
            ch=='W'||ch=='x'||ch=='X'||ch=='y'||ch=='Y'||
            ch=='z'||ch=='Z')
                letters++;
            else if(ch==0||ch==1||ch==2||ch==3||ch==4||
                    ch==5||ch==5||ch==6||ch==7||ch==8||
                    ch==9)
                digits ++;
            else if(ch==' ')
                blanks ++;
        }
        System.out.println("Letters : " +letters);
        System.out.println("Digits : " +digits);
        System.out.println("Blanks : " +blanks);
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String original="",reverse="";
        int length=0,digits=0,blanks=0,letters=0;
        char ch=' ';
        Scanner peace=new Scanner(System.in);
        String func1=PalindromeChecker(original,reverse);
        System.out.println(func1);
        CharacterNumberCounter(original);
    }
}
```

Why isn't my program displaying the number of characters,numbers and whitespaces? I was required to use a function to do this things. First I was told to display if the entered string is a palindrome or not using function, so I succeeded but when I did the next one is it always displays the number of char,num,whitespaces is 0.

Comment: Generally, you get banned from asking questions by asking *bad* questions - which you've done again. You've presented a dump of code, ranted at the community, but not given a clear example of "I presented the code with input X, got result Y, but expected result Z." Ideally, you should explain what diagnostics you've perfomed as well - debugging etc. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints - and then edit your old bad questions instead of asking *new* bad quesitons.

Comment: @JonSkeet First is, yes ok I admit. Let's say for you this is bad. But let me justify myself, I posted the code with explaining what it does. Please read it all before you start saying I just posted without knowing anyway. Thanks.

Comment: I agree I hadn't originally seen that it was always displaying 0 - your rant against the community was obscuring it somewhat. But you still haven't given any indication of what you've done to diagnose the issue. (Hint: just a tiny bit of using the debugger would have discovered the problem for you. What is the value of `original` in your `CharacterNumberCounter` method?) The code you've posted doesn't even *compile* though, so it doesn't produce the output you're claiming. It's still a bad question. Read the link I included in my first comment.

Comment: It compiled in my JCreator buddy. Why won't it compile in yours.

Comment: Ah, you've fixed it in an edit. The code in your original post (where you used `original.length` rather than `original.length()`) didn't compile.

Comment: Yes yes. My bad. Ok so it compiled now. So i looked and looked where is the problem sorry I really can't find it.

Comment: And did you use a debugger? Did you look at the value of `original` at the start of `CharacterNumberCounter`? (Why do you have two parameters to that method anyway, when you're not using one of them?)

Comment: Wait wait, where do I find the debugger?.

Comment: Okay, this is now well out of the scope of Stack Overflow. While SO is great at answering specific questions, it's not meant to replace learning how to program from a book, class, tutorial or whatever. We don't have any context as to whether you're taking a class etc, but if you are, you should *definitely* ask your teacher for help. We're not going to handhold you through learning to use a debugger.

Comment: Ok I edited the program on top. It still displays 0.

Comment: My last comment in this thread: if you haven't learned to use a debugger, now is the time to do so. Stop trying to solve this problem until you have a decent idea of how to reason about your code, *at least* through logging (e.g. `System.out.println` at its simplest) but preferrably with an interactive debugger too. Otherwise we could solve this problem for you and you'd just have another one in 5 minutes and be no better off.

Comment: @JonSkeet Sir I believe my Compiler doesn't have a debugger. -_- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466400/how-to-debug-in-jcreator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PalindromeChecker is best defined as boolean. I have used recursion for checking for palindrome. 
Instead of a very long char check condition using `|| OR`, checking for the ascii values, seemed to be better. You could use regex also.

Changed your code, but here it is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test1
{
    public static boolean PalindromeChecker(String s)
    {
        if(s.length() == 0 || s.length() == 1)
            return true;
        if(s.charAt(0) == s.charAt(s.length()-1))
            return PalindromeChecker(s.substring(1, s.length()-1));
        return false;
    }
    public static void CharacterNumberCounter(String original) 
    {
        int letters=0,digits=0,blanks=0,length=0;
        char ch;
        for(int i=0;i<original.length();i++)
        {
            ch=original.charAt(i);
            if((ch>=65 && ch<=90 ) ||(ch>=97 && ch<=122 ))
                letters++;
            else if(ch>=48 && ch<=57 )
                digits ++;
            else if(ch==' ')
                blanks ++;
        }
        System.out.println("Letters : " +letters);
        System.out.println("Digits : " +digits);
        System.out.println("Blanks : " +blanks);
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
                Scanner peace=new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Enter String for Palindrome check");
                System.out.println(PalindromeChecker(peace.nextLine()));
                System.out.println("Enter String for Char count ");
                CharacterNumberCounter(peace.nextLine());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there any way where you can just display the counted letters,numbers and blanks without asking the user to input another string?. Like after you display if it is a palindrome or not, you display those things too.

Comment: `public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner peace=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter String for Palindrome check");
        String input = peace.nextLine();
        System.out.println(PalindromeChecker(input));
        CharacterNumberCounter(input);
    }`

Comment: Thank you very much sir!. :-) Happy to know there are still programmers here who ain't arrogant and such. Stay Humble always sir. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be calling the method

```
public static void CharacterNumberCounter(String func1,String original)
```

with the arguments in the wrong order

```
CharacterNumberCounter(original,func1);
```

In the CharacterNumberCounter method you are counting the character occurrences from the string in the second argument. But you call the method with the second argument func1 (which at that point in the program is set to the empty string "")

Comment: Oh it's worse than "in the wrong order". There are huge problems with all of this, basically...

Comment: @aniri Ok so I fixed the one you pointed out. But still. It didn't solve the problem.